# Python Tkinter - save canvas - tkinter crashes

Tags: python, save, tkinter

I'm trying to save my canvas using the postscript method, and Tkinter crashes...

```
w.postscript(file="my_drawing.ps", colormode='color')
```

gets the exception:

```
w.postscript(file="my_drawing.ps", colormode='color')
File "C:\python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2307, in postscript
self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".57816328L"
```

I'm not sure what this error means - has anyone encountered that before?

I tried without the color option too, with no avail.

---

Edit - widgit stripped down to basics gives same error:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=1000)
w.pack()
w.create_oval(450,550,550,450)
mainloop()
w.postscript(file="my_drawing.ps")
```

Comment: This code worked for me using the oval, text and rectangle. I suspect the problem relates to a local configuration issue. That said, if you want to post the complete canvas code, I'm happy to execute it here to see if I can reproduce the error. If you just need an image, could you take a screenshot?

Comment: @ABS I can post the complete code - all the object are dynamically created, so you would need the whole script right? I want to automate the process, so screen shots are less ideal..

Comment: To simplify, it might help if you run a shorter script with fewer objects and see if you still get the error. If yes, let's fix the shorter script first. If not, you can continue adding back code until you see what breaks.

Comment: oh, good plan, I'lll have a look, thanks.

Comment: @ABS I added the most basic I could, and it still crashes - I guess its a local implementation thing - I'll check it on my work machine when I get in the office in a couple of hours. Maybe need to reinstall Tkinter from a different source?

Comment: It appears you're using Windows. From reading this:http://wiki.tcl.tk/949, you might need to send your output through ghostscript to work. If you have a *nix system at work, you should be able to avoid that.

Comment: Ah, I am on windows. OK. thats a thread to follow, it looks a bit complex for me, but I'll see if I can't make sense of it. The other fix I found was to port the drawing to PIL - that might be less painful... thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 @JayGattuso I see the same thing as you in Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work if you simply move the `w.postscript()` call above the `mainloop()` call. This means that the error is due to calling `w.postscript()` *after* the Tkinter GUI is closed (since mainloop() runs until the window is closed).

I noticed this was a difference between your code and [this example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216929), so I tried it and saw that the .ps file was created as soon as the script is ran.

Comment: Yupe. Nailed it. Thank you. And it makes sense too.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `print()` statements execute fine if you put it after `mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update for python 3:

Please note that:
- a call to `update` on the canvas is necessary.
- The `Canvas` background is not saved.
- Only the visible part of canvas is saved.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

COLORS = ["white", "black", "red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "yellow", "magenta"]

root = tk.Tk()

cv = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000, bg='cyan')
cv.pack()

for _ in range(1000):
    coordinates = [random.randrange(0, 1000) for _ in range(4)]
    cv.create_oval(*coordinates, outline=random.choice(COLORS))

cv.update()
cv.postscript(file="my_drawing.ps")

mainloop()
```

[image]